# When will the onLoaderReset() be called by the system?

Tags: java, android

Can you let me know the possible scenarios. Im using loaders to fetch data from a server and parse the JSON results using AsyncLoader

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/understanding-loadermanager.html) will help